# Paste snapshot of range without distortion

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using this code to export a map in png format from excel to a folder Mycharts located on the Desktop. But this image get distorted while reaching to the specified folder.

```
Sub ExportMap()
    Dim day As Integer
    day = Worksheets("Control").Range("$J$1").Value
    Worksheets("Map").Range("B2:L43").CopyPicture xlScreen, xlPicture
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set oCht = Charts.Add
    If day = 1 Then
    With oCht
        .Paste
        .Export Filename:="...\Mycharts\FCT_Day_1.png",  filtername:="PNG"
        .Delete
    End With
    End If
    If day = 2 Then
    With oCht
        .Paste
        .Export Filename:="...\Mycharts\FCT_Day_2.png", filtername:="PNG"
        .Delete
    End With
    End If
    If day = 3 Then
    With oCht
        .Paste
        .Export Filename:="..\Mycharts\FCT_Day_3.png", filtername:="PNG"
        .Delete
    End With
    End If   
End Sub
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include a title that actually describes the problem you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

Use an [Excel.ChartObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194426.aspx) and resize it to suit the pixel size of the source to avoid distortion and pixelating.

```
Sub ExportMap()
    Dim dy As Integer, pxHeight As Integer, pxWidth As Integer
    Dim oCht As Excel.ChartObject

    dy = Worksheets("Control").Range("J1").Value  '<~~ J1 is text; it's not going anywhere

    With Worksheets("Map")
        With .Range("B2:L43")
            .CopyPicture xlScreen, xlPicture
            'get the dimensions of the screen shot
            pxHeight = .Height
            pxWidth = .Width
        End With
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        With .ChartObjects.Add(10, 10, pxWidth, pxHeight)
            Select Case dy
                Case 1, 2, 3
                    .Chart.Paste
                    .Chart.Export Filename:=Environ("TMP") & "\FCT_Day_" & dy & ".png", filtername:="PNG"
                    .Delete
                Case Else
                    'do nothing
            End Select
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

I've tried to tighten up your multiple If ... Else ... End Ifs with a [Select Case statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278665.aspx) and concatenated the **dy** (note: not the same name as the VBA's native [Day function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b4h8sxy.aspx)) into the file name.

Comment: Thank Jeeped ji. It has solved my problem and also shorten the code. one again many many thanks for quick response.